# How to highlight matching ternary expression operators in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, syntax-highlighting, conditional-operator

I am writing a React application using JSX in WebStorm. My team's codebase has become quite complex in terms of the control flow, and there are several deeply nested ternary boolean expressions in order to avoid nested if statements before the return statement.

Is there a feature, plugin or setting that would allow me to see what the corresponding `?` or `:` symbol is that matches with the other symbol as there is with curly brackets?

Even a solution in VSCode or Atom would be fine, as I would try to find something similar in WebStorm. It would vastly improve my quality of life during this project, since I wouldn't have to spend a minute or so to find the original condition. I couldn't find anything in the plugins marketplace or online.

The expression works one-to-one, I believe, so the matching operator is not ambiguous, correct?

```
return (
    <TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => setActivePlayer(index)} style={
        [styles.streamContainer, index % 2 === 0 ?
                fullscreen === true && (secondaryPlayer === index || quaternaryPlayer === index) ?
                    {right: 0} : {}
                :
                fullscreen === true && (activePlayer === index || tertiaryPlayer === index) ?
                    {}
                    :
                    {right: 0},
\\...
```

Something like this would be amazing:
[image: Matching curly brackets]

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but that expression should be equivalent to `fullscreen && [activePlayer, secondaryPlayer, tertiaryPlayer, quaternaryPlayer].indexOf(index) % 2 ? { right: 0 } : {}`

Comment: also not an answer but you could enforce parentheses around operands with Prettier, that would be more efficient than jumping between operators with hotkeys

Comment: OP Please update if you found anything useful, running with exactly this problem on VScode. Thanks.